Can a limit of degenerate two-cocycles be non-degenerate?
Let $G$ be a discrete abelian group and $\omega\colon G\times G\to\mathbb{T}$ a two-cocycle on $G$. We say that $\omega$ is non-degenerate if for every $e\neq g\in G$ there exists $h\in G$ such that $\omega(g,h)\neq 1$.
Let $G=\oplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Z}$, $\omega$ a two-cocycle on $G$, and denote by $\omega_n$ the restriction of $\omega$ to $\mathbb{Z}^n=\oplus_{i=1}^n\mathbb{Z}$.
My question is fairly simple: if $\omega$ is non-degenerate and $m\in\mathbb{N}$, does there always exist some $n\geq m$ such that $\omega_n$ is non-degenerate?

Fix $u\in\mathbb{T}$ of infinite order. Let $(e_i)$ be the canonical basis of $G$. For $m$ coprime to $3$, define $v_3(3^km)=k$. For $i$ such that $v_3(i)$ is even, define $\omega(e_i,e_{3i})=-\omega(e_{3i},e_i)=u$, and define $\omega(e_j,e_k)=0$ in other cases. Then $\omega$ is degenerate on $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n$ for every $n\ge 1$.

@YCor Thanks a lot!

@YCor thinking about this again, I actually wonder about something a bit more general: If $\omega$ is non-degenerate, does there always exist some sequence of finitely generated subgroups $G_i$ such that the restrictions $\omega_i$ are non-degenerate and $G=\cup G_i$? Or do you have a counterexample to this as well?

Yes, this should be true.

@YCor Could you any hints about how you think one can prove it?
